# Scraping heirarchical data with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

The website I am trying to scrape has the following pages:

- A list of all books
- An info page of the book with all its chapters
- When you click a chapter, the first page will be displayed, and a drop-down of all the pages for that chapter will be available

So far so good. I am able to scrape all the data I need, but the only problem is to reference a page to its chapter, or a chapter to its book. I've read about passing the book info to the meta like this:

```
scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_chapter, meta={book: book})
```

But I can't figure out how to reference them in my item pipeline. Any help?

Comment: add field `book` to `Item` and put this information and you will have it in pipeline functions.

Comment: The problem is how can I retrieve the 'book_id' in my database, will it be safe to assume that the book is already created before saving its chapters?

Comment: I think you have two possible workflows and the decision which one is better is an application/domain question: Either you could create each of the three types individually (i.e. yield `BookItem` from the books list, `ChapterItem` from the chapters list and so on). Or you pass information on through `meta` and yield a `BookWithChaptersAndPagesItem` (name should just clarify that it includes all information) and write that at the end.

Comment: `BookWithChaptersAndPagesItem` is what I would like to achieve, can you help me with that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess there is no way to reference the items during crawls. Save them in one table then segregate the records after scraping.

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: You could save them and segregate them in many ways. You could have each page be a new item and then you could have a book column and sort them by book, chapter and page. There's literally infinite ways.

Answer (score 0):

Your meta call is missing quotes. You can set the meta field correctly and obtain it in your callback function as follows:

```
# Meta is a python dictionary so you must use dictionary syntax.
yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_chapters meta={'item': item})

def parse_chapters(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
```

You can literally store anything in a scrapy item field. You could define your item as follows:

```
class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    f = scrapy.Field()
    book = f
    chapters = f
    pages = f
```

Each time you go to a new page you would pass your item in and retrieve it. You could store a list of all chapters and pages. Or if you want to store nested items you could store a dictionary like follows:

```
dict = {"Book": "Moby Dick", "Chapters": {"1": ["page1", "page2", "page3"]
                                          "2": ["page4", "page5", "page6" ]}
# Now you only need 1 field in your item I believe you must save as string
item['book'] = str(dict)
```

That's the best I can do with the limited information you have provided. If you want to supply some code and ask clear questions I will attempt to help you further.

PS: Feel free to edits as I'm sure there are mistakes here.